# Config BigBlueButton Using External Freeswitch

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have trouble when I tried to config my BBB server using external freeswitch.

Here is my configuration step:

**Step 1:** I use `bbb-install.sh` script and install two BBB server

Here is my install script

`wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v xenial-220-2.2.25 -s abbb.vdc2.com.vn -e naphaluan211092@gmail.com -w -g`

Then I have two BBB server with IP, domain and role like bellow:

I also turn of all BBB service on server Freeswitch (IP:203.162.141.13) like this:

**Step 2:** I follow this guide ([Connect BigBlueButton to an external FreeSWITCH Server](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/customize.html#connect-bigbluebutton-to-an-external-freeswitch-server)) to config my BBB server to external freeswitch:

*3. On BBB server (203.162.141.15)*

I edit file /usr/share/red5/webapps/sip/WEB-INF/bigbluebutton-sip.properties

Change

Keepp value:

*4. On Freeswitch External server (203.162.141.13)*

*5. On BBB server (203.162.141.15)*

*6. On BBB server (203.162.141.15)*

*7. On BBB server (203.162.141.15)*

**Step 3:**

I restart server BBB (203.162.141.15) and turn off freeswitch server

[image]

And here is my `bbb-conf --check` output

**Step 4:**

I connect BBB server:

*1. When I use listen only mode:*

*2. When I use micro mode:*

I don't understand where it's wrong.
Please help me.